# Loading jsTree Children from JSON

Tags: jquery, jstree

I'm fairly new to JavaScript coding, specifically on using jQuery. I'm trying to use jsTree trying to populate it through JSON. Now I believe my question had been answered on related questions but I can't seem to find a specific answer to what I'm doing. I have referred to the jsTree documentation as well, but I still can't figure it out.

below is the code I'm trying out

```
buildTree : function(name, url, nodeRef) {

     $("#"+name).jstree({ 
      "json_data" : {
    "ajax" : {
     "url" : url + nodeRef,
     "data" : function(n) {
      return { id : n.attr ? n.attr("id") : 0 };
     }
    }
   },

   "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data" ]
  });
    }
```

this is basically a copy of the code in the jsTree documentation for JSON. What's happening here is I am able to populate the root folder of the tree of it's contents. Below is the response of the JSON I'm getting.

```
[
 {
 "attr":{"id":"a3e6a1f0-ec50-4215-a6df-2065eb09115e","rel":"file"},
 "data":"File 1","state":""
 },
 {
 "attr":{"id":"b38e4a72-875b-4d69-95d3-5437f7e65575","rel":"folder"},
 "data":"Folder 1","state":"closed"
 }
]
```

But when I click the the node of the folder, It is being populated by the same JSON request, having the same values.

I know the culprit is

```
"url" : url + nodeRef,
```

but I am lost on how I'm going to pass the ID I'm getting from the response, replacing the initial nodeRef value. I have tried using the callbacks but nothing is happening.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following part in your code already takes care of appending an "id" querystring parameter to the ajax url. The function returns an object with key/value pairs that will be used for querystring parameters for the url to be requested.

```
"data" : function(n) {       return { id : n.attr ? n.attr("id") : 0 };      }
```

I am not sure what the purpose of the nodeRef variable is in your code. Is it to find the root node? If so, could you not use a different querystring parameter for that?

Use fiddler to confirm the urls constructed by jsTree are what you expect it to be. Perhaps it's currently creating a url with two id querystring parameters and it always uses the one provided by your nodeRef variable?